# Add new child entity and update parent entity in one turn

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox, foreign-key-relationship, invalidoperationexception

I have table `entry` and a table `type`. An `entry` has a `type` a type can be in many entries (n-to-1 relation). The type is displayed in an editable ComboBox. If the user enters a type which is not yet existing it should be created and the `type` of the related `entry` should be updated to the new type-entity.

How I load the entries (eagerly loading):

```
var entries = dbContext.entry.Include(entry => entry.type).ToList();
```

How I bind the type to the Combobox:

```
<Combobox IsEditable="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllTypes, Source={StaticResource typeTableController}}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path="Entry.type"}" />
```

`typeTableController` has a property (`AllTypes`) with all existing types in the DB. `Entry` is the currently selected `entry`. The user can now edit the ComboBox text. If he presses a "Save" button this type should be added to the DB if not existing yet, or it should be selected if existing. And the updated entry should be saved. It would be great if I don't have to handle every property on its own because `type` is not the only one I have.

My first approaches:

```
dbContext.Set(entry.getType()).Attach(entry);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

-> *InvalidOperationException: referential integrity constraint violation*

or

```
dbContext.Entry(formEntry.type).State = EntityState.Added;
dbContext.Set(entry.getType()).Add(entry);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

-> Adds the new `type` to the type table BUT also duplicates all types and entries in the type/entry table (that is really strange for me) and only updates the type of one of the now two existing `entries` to the new `type`. So if there were 10 types before, there are now 21.

**Edit: my entry:**

```
public partial class entry 
{
    ...
    public Nullable<int> type_id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual type type { get; set; }
}
```

**Important:**
I always got crashes when I try

```
dbContext.Entry(entry).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

The reason was, that I had `entry` in my debugger watchlist. It seems that this leads to some conflicts. Removing it fixes that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine if type is existing one or new added by user. Check `type.Id == 0` for new type entity.

```
if (typeFromCombobox.Id == 0){
    //new type added
    dbContext.Set<type>().Add(typeFromCombobox)
}
entity.type = typeFromCombobox // EF should handle this if you didn't call 'Detach' before
dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

**Edit**: not sure about that: you are using combobox binding which should automatically change `entity.type` when user select it. So line `entity.type = typeFromCombobox` is rebundant

**Edit 2**: I created [sample code](https://gist.github.com/Benzeliden/880b23c9e8229ef924d372e6f4fbcc86)

It works fine and both `entity.typeid` and `entity.type.id` were updated after `SaveChanges` call

But if I uncomment `this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` `entity.typeid` won't be updated until I call `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` manually

**Edit 3**: If you changed dbContext between load and save you should attach you entity to new context

```
dbContext.Set<entity>().Attach(entity);
if (typeFromCombobox.Id == 0){
    //new type added
    dbContext.Set<type>().Add(typeFromCombobox)
}
entity.type = typeFromCombobox;
dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: With your code the new type will be added. But the entry's foreign key is not updated in the db. I'm not sure what you mean with "Detach". I am not in the context anymore I created when loading the entries.

Comment: @L3n95 you mean `entry.typeId` foreign key? Usually EF should handle this when you do assignment of navigation property

Comment: Yes. Before the update: entry.type_id = 55, entry.type.id = 0; After the update: entry.type_id = 55, entry.type.id = 56

Comment: @L3n95 what is the difference between `_id` and `id` in your application? Seems like EF properly works with `id` field but doesn't know about `_id`

Comment: The class entry has the property: public Nullable<int> type_id and the property: public virtual type type which itself has the property id. This was created by the Entitiy Framework. So type_id exists in the entry and type.id is in the type.

Comment: @L3n95 did you turn off `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` in your context?

Comment: So your code works great but the type_id is not synchronized with the type.id. No I didn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139344/discussion-between-denis-krasakov-and-l3n95).